# SharePoint2010 FieldDefinition FullHtml Field, need to prohibit script tags

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

I have a rather tricky problem. I have a SharePoint 2010 list definition. In this definition I have a field defined, like so:

```
<Field ID="{AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAA}"
            Name="MyComponentHTMLTemplate"
            DisplayName="HTML template"
            Type ="HTML"
        Description="HTML template for (my component)."
            StaticName=MyComponentHTMLTemplate"
        RichText ="FALSE"
        RichTextMode ="FullHtml"
            Required="FALSE">
        <Default>
          <![CDATA[<a href='{URL}' title='{DESCRIPTION}'>{KEYWORD}</a>]]>
        </Default>
      </Field>
```

As you can see, the field accepts html tags. This is desired behavior. However, there's one thing the field mustn't accept - `<scrpit>` tags.

```
<a href='{URL}' title='{DESCRIPTION}'>{KEYWORD}<script>alert.('this is not allowed')</script></a>
```

This is to prevent cross-site scripting and similar shenanigans. How can I set the field to accept, html, but not script tags? So far my google searches have yielded no answer. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I just got further in my search. I believe I need to set either the SPField.ValidationFormula property or SPField.ValidationEcmaScript property (or both), which is consistent with what little instruction I got (I was told some sort of javascript should be used to validate the input). As per usual, MSDN pages on those properties contain jack, other than a mention of their existence. I'll google further of course, but help would still be appreciated.